# Settling in HTMX

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to use a CSS transition in a similar manner to https://htmx.org/examples/bulk-update/ to show which row was updated, but I can't get it to work for my example using HTMX 1.3.3

The relevant HTML is:

```
<div id="replace-me">
  <div id="A" hx-get="/A" hx-target="#replace-me" hx-select="#replace-me" hx-swap="outerHTML">A</div> 
  <div id="B" hx-get="/B" hx-target="#replace-me" hx-select="#replace-me" hx-swap="outerHTML">B</div>
</div>
```

When either div A or div B is clicked, the server returns the above HTML again, but with `class="updated"` applied to the div in question.

I also have the following CSS:

```
.htmx-settling .updated {
  background: darkseagreen;
}

.updated {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I would expect to see the clicked div show a border and also flash green. However what I observe is:

- I click on div A.
- div A shows a border *but does not flash*.
- I click on div B.
- div B shows a border, *but div A flashes*.
- From then on, the div that I click on shows a border, but the div that was clicked on the previous turn flashed.

I'm guessing this is something to do with the timing of the application/removal of the `htmx-settling` class combined with when the swapped content gains the new class. I've read https://htmx.org/docs/#request-operations and https://htmx.org/docs/#css_transitions, but can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

AFIAK you need `transition` in you CSS, like from https://htmx.org/docs/#css_transitions

```
.red {
  color: red;
  transition: all ease-in 1s ; <========= missing?
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the solution. The transition affects the rate at which the CSS property is applied, but my problem is that the CSS property is being applied to the wrong element.